# Magento Add extra fee in checkout

Tags: checkout

I want to add a checkbox in the checkout for customer to click if they want an extra service and if they click, an extra fixed fee must be added to the subtotal.

How can I add the fixed fee when the customer select the checkbox?

I found the github reference https://github.com/magentix/Fee

but I couldn't manage to implement the click event and adding the fee

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is not that difficult to achieve.

I do this on a site to inject a donation item to the cart / order at checkout review.

I extracted the code for you to Github here: https://github.com/ProxiBlue/Donation

a quick explain:

- uses a product as the 'service' product - so you have control over price etc
- at review a block is injected that allows user to check-da-box, which will insert / remove the noted products.
- controlled from admin - system->configuration->proxiblue donation - you set it enabled, and note the product id to use

I can put all the code here (as we prefer not to have link-fests), but I am a bit busy right now, sorry.

The short version is that the block checkbox calls the js:

```
function updateDonation(id) {
        var container = $('review-buttons-container');
        container.addClassName('disabled');
        container.setStyle({opacity:.8});
        checkout._disableEnableAll(container, true);
        Element.show('donation-please-wait');
        if($(id).checked) {
            var url = 'donation/donation/add';
        } else {
            var url = 'donation/donation/remove';
        }
        new Ajax.Request('/' + url , {
            onComplete: function(response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
                checkout.reloadReviewBlock();
            }
        });
    }
```

which in turns makes an ajax call to the correct url
in the controller, the items is either added/removed from the cart :

```
/**
     * Add product to cart
     */
    public function addAction() {
        $response = $this->_product->getName() . Mage::helper('proxiblue_donation')->__(' was added to your order.');
        try {
            $cartHelper = Mage::helper('checkout/cart');
            $items = $cartHelper->getCart()->getItems();
            $isIncart = false;
            foreach ($items as $item) {
                if ($item->getProduct()->getId() == $this->_giftItemId){
                    $isIncart = true;
                    //Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
                    break;
                }
            }

            if ($isIncart === false){
                $cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
                $cart->addProduct($this->_product);
                $cart->save();

                Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(false);
            }    
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $response = Mage::helper('proxiblue_donation')->__('We coudn\'t add the donation to your shopping bag.');
            Mage::logException($e);
        }
        $this->getResponse()->setBody($response);
        return $this;
    }
```

and upon result reloads the review block, via the core reload call.

`checkout.reloadReviewBlock();`

Hope that helps.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Could it not be added as a custom option or even a configurable option to your product sets? then the option is presented to the customer when buying the product it's attributed to?

Alternatively you could create a separate "service product" and link to it in the checkout?

Regards.

Comment: My customer requested to ask for a service in the checkout and if the site customer accepts i by checking the checkbox, the extra fee will be added. But maybe I can do it with a service product but how can I link the service product in the checkout? @Joe Whitehead

Comment: You could probably create a function to do this, although as the checkbox would be live on the checkout but you'd probably need to do it with AJAX. You could add the link in the checkout simply by editing your checkout template override and putting a block in there.